# Error while checking textfield length

Tags: ios, swift

I am using below code to put some condition for textfield length

```
if(textfield.text?.count>0){}
```

But this is throwing error

> Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String.IndexDistance?' (aka 'Optional') and 'Int'

Comment: You should unwrap the value in the left to compare the two values.

Comment: as the4kman said do like this `if(textfield.text!.count > 0){}
`

Comment: @Saurabh Please try to use this :  if(textField.text?.characters.count>0){
                
            }

Comment: You can't compare optional values, make sure both sides values are unwraped.